# How to add an empty Map into Firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to add an empty Map into firestore in the Update function?

This is my code for updating some values in the database. I want the `users` value to be an empty Map. It shouldn't contain any kind of empty child values in it like how I have in my code.

```
addEventDetails() async {
if (_eventNameTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
    _eventDescTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
    _eventLocationTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
    _eventTicketPriceTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
    formattedDate != null) {
  documentReference.update({
    "createdBy": orgUid,
    "eventName": _eventNameTextEditingController.text,
    "eventDesc": _eventDescTextEditingController.text,
    "eventLoc": _eventLocationTextEditingController.text,
    "ticketPrice": _eventTicketPriceTextEditingController.text,
    "eventDate": formattedDate,
    "addedDate": addedDate,
    "eventId": documentReference.id,
    "users.emptyValue": {},
  });
  await displayDialog("Event added successfully!");
  clearValues();
  // Navigator.push(
  //     context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrgHomePage()));
} else {
  displayDialog("Please fill all the fields");
}
}
```

This is the result I need.
[image: Database Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fields without values are not stored in Firestore, and thus are not shown in the Firebase console.

A common practice is to store default values, for example empty strings, in those fields. An empty string **is** a value, so the field will be stored when you make its value an empty string, and thus it will show up in the console.